# Discard headings in res.read() status text

Tags: python, django

This line `status_msg = res.read()` get a status message...

```
some heading|more headings|even more heading
0|OK|eb725f96b4b094d5f8318741cc1a545f-2
```

However, I want status_msg to discard the first line of text (headings) and only get the **second** line starting at 0.

Thanks.

```
res = urllib.urlopen(self.base_url, data)
status_msg = res.read()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `res.readlines()`, It returns a list of lines of resulting message

```
status_msg = '\n'.join(res.readlines()[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split on lines:

```
status_msg = '\n'.join(res.read().splitlines()[1:])
```

or even:

```
status_msg = '\n'.join(res.readlines()[1:])
```

or call `.readline()` on the response to discard the first line:

```
res.readline()  # discard the first line
status_msg = res.read()
```